# Replacement for Autopager in Chrome

Tags: chrome

I used [Autopager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autopager/) for a while. It hasn't been updated in a while ([as evident by the third party update here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autopager-fixed/)), and the Chrome version hasn't been working much for me at all.

I would love that functionality again, it made catching up on articles and comics easy and fast. And the best part was being able to custom make the rules for sites that may not have them, which I always had issues with on the Chrome version.

I generally use Windows (and am switching to Ubuntu for a lot of things), but I think something like this should be cross compatible as it runs in a browser.

So I would like something:

- With "autopaging," or loading page after page into the same page
- With custom XPath generation, preferrably with a tester and GUI, but that isn't necessary
- Fully featured in Chrome
- Up to date and currently being updated so that it is usable in the future
- Preferably free
- That works in Windows 7
- Possibly OS agnostic